# Android Unit Test :- Class not found "package name " Empty test suite

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

Getting this error with message :-

Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: “com.example.app.ken.finding_driver.instant.FindingDriverFlowTest” Empty test suite.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check and make sure - your **Java source code path** and **test class path** should be exactly same. Log-cat did not show this error

[image]